# How can an Azure Function App interact with Azure resources?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a c# funtion app, I want to use this app to make automated updates to an Azure Network Security Group under the same subscription.

The function app is behind Azure AD authentication which works fine, I can get the user details.

The next step is to somehow access the Azure objects, all the examples of this I have seen use the following namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
```

However, adding this and compiling the function app, I get an error:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have tried to add in a reference:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent"
```

But doing this gives me another error:

```
    error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent' could not be found
```

All the samples I have seen use syntax like:

```
var azure = Azure.Configure().WithDefaultSubscription();
```

However they don't explain how the function app is able to reference `Azure` as an object. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to work with the relevant Nuget pacakges in your application. Here are a couple of them to get you started, but you may need more depending on what you're trying to do further:

- [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/)
- [Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent](http://Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent) (for app services)
- [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) (for resource group and resource management)

Another important consideration will be **how you authenticate**

There are a fews ways.. You can find good details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md)

- **Through a cred file** in your solution (experimental and subject to change, so wouldn't be recommended)

  ```
  Azure azure = Azure.Authenticate("my.azureauth").WithDefaultSubscription();
  ```
- **Through Service principal** registration

  Using client secret

  ```
  var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(client, key, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
  var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
  ```

  Using certificate

  ```
  var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(client, pfxCertificatePath, password, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
  var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
  ```
- **Using Managed Service Identity or MSI**

  ```
  AzureCredentialsFactory factory = new AzureCredentialsFactory();
  AzureCredentials msiCred = factory.FromMSI(new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.AppService), AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
  var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(msiCred).WithDefaultSubscription();
  ```

Here is the root level documentation and code samples for [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#azure-management-libraries-for-net)

Here are samples specific to Azure Functions that may help you: [Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#ready-to-run-code-samples-for-application-services)

---

You have mentioned that you want to work with NSG's as part of your function, so I quickly tried out one at my end.

I used the 3rd way to authenticate explained above, by first enabling MSI for my Azure Function. Here are the steps that I had to do:

1. Enable Managed Service Identity for my Function App

   [image]
2. Give permissions for working with NSG to my Function App's MSI

   [image]

Here is the full (quick & dirty) working code..  using the above mentioned Nuget pacakges

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RSFunctionCallingFluent
{
    public static class SimpleFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("SimpleFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            AzureCredentialsFactory factory = new AzureCredentialsFactory();
            AzureCredentials msiCred = factory.FromMSI(new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.AppService), AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(msiCred).WithDefaultSubscription();

            var nsg = azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.GetByResourceGroup("TestNSGRG", "RSTestNSG1");

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(string.Format("NSG {0} found with {1} default security rules", nsg.Name, nsg.DefaultSecurityRules.Count));
        }
    }
}
```

Final Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I've added references to the Fluent package via Nuget but it seems there's a conflict with Newtonsoft.Json - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIN1L.png - Is this normal? It now prompts to change the function runtime version (from ~2 to ~1) when I publish via VS.

Comment: @bendataclear I tried out a function app using the same packages and trying to work with NSG as you mention.. I have shared the code and steps above.. I did not face the issue you have mentioned above... just to be clear I am working with VS 2017 and 2.0 runtime.. I did come across a thread similar to the issue you mention, although this is unanswered.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476297/error-with-installing-the-dependencies-for-azure-function-creation

Comment: I was able to get past the error by completely removing the Function App, creating a new one with the same name, creating a new project in VS2017 then re-publishing to Azure. Once I  did this I was able to follow your instructions to update NSG's successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent

Azure Resource Manager resource Fluent 
Provides resource group and resource management (Fluent) capabilities for Microsoft Azure.

OR

Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/azure-sdk?page=2